# delete array position in node js not work

Tags: arrays, node.js

The delete does not remove the position of the array, there is another way to delete the position of the array?

```
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {       
    delete users[socket.data];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users));     
    socket.leave(socket.data);
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users.splice(socket.data, 1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice